# Elastic search indices are getting recreated after deletion

Tags: elasticsearch

1. We are running single node cluster, as a single instance.
2. Filebeat is the log forwarder for logstash.
3. We have indices like

   abc_12.06.2018
   abc_13.06.2018

With 5 primary shards and 1 replica shard.
When I delete abc_12.06.2018, it is getting deleted at that moment and slowly after some time index is getting recreated.
The same is happening with replica 0 as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Filebeat just write logs to index, that you deleted and recreate it. Root cause isn't in elasticsearch.
Does "recreated" indices have any data?

Comment: Yes, data is also available.